# I want to write a program to find the coordinate number for each letter on the phone pad. I wote like this

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConvertLetterToNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter one letter");
        String str = input.next();
        char ch = str.charAt(0);

        switch (ch){
        case 'A': case 'a': case 'B': case 'b': case 'C': case 'c':
            System.out.println("the number is 2");
            break;
        case 'D': case 'd': case 'E': case 'e': case 'F': case 'f':
            System.out.println("the number is 3");
            break;
        case 'G': case 'g': case 'H': case 'h': case 'I': case 'i':  
            System.out.println("the number is 4");
            break;
        case 'J': case 'j': case 'K': case 'k': case 'L': case 'l':
            System.out.println("the number is 5");
            break;
        case 'M': case 'm': case 'N': case 'n': case 'O': case 'o':
            System.out.println("the number is 6");
            break;
        case 'P':case 'p': case 'Q': case 'q': case 'R': case 'r': case 'S': case's':
            System.out.println("the number is 7");
            break;
        case 'T':case 't':case 'U':case'u':case'V':case 'v':
            System.out.println("the number is 8");
            break;
        case 'W':case 'w':case 'X': case 'x': case 'Y':case'y':case 'Z':case 'z':
            System.out.println("the number is 9");
            break;
        default :System.out.println("Error:invalid input");
        System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is if I enter two or more letters at one time (for example "ab" the answer will be "2", but what I want is "Invalid input". How can I add this instruction to ask user to enter only one letter?

Comment: Why are you only taking the first character `char ch = str.charAt(0);` if you want to check the full input?

Comment: you could eliminate half of your `case` by just doing a toLower() on your character... and if you want to check multiple characters, then don't use `charAt()` which will only ever return a single character anyways.

Comment: Do you really need System.exit(1) ?

Comment: @Marc B It's a very good tip about eliminating my case! And the question is asking me to let user enter only one letter, not two or more, for example :input a and output:2

Comment: @ergonaut could you give me a hint about what else should I use?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you can just remove System.exit(1) altogether.  Unless you are checking the return code from an outside caller to the program, you probably don't care.

Comment: then check the length of the input. if it's `!= 1`, they entered something "illegal".

Comment: @Delimanolis Because the question is to ask user to enter one letter only, I don't know how to show "invalid input" when entered more letters

Comment: @Marc B Yes! I added the .length() method and I got what I want! Thank you so much!

Comment: @ergonaut You are right. It seems I don't need to use the System.exit(1). I eliminated it and the answer doesn't change. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the str length before your switch, and return like so:

```
if (str.length > 1){
    return;
}
```

Comment: Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter one letter");
        String str = input.next();
        String ch = (str.substring(0)).toUpperCase();
        
        if (ch.length()>1){
            System.out.println("Invalide input.Plaease Enter only one chacater");
        }
        else 
        switch (ch){
        case "A": case "B": case "C":
         System.out.println("the number is 2");
         break;
        ........

        default:System.out.println("Invalid input.Please enter a letter");
        
        }
 }
}
That's what I did.seems correct